# Распознавание лиц, проверка открыты ли глаза

Tags: android, c#, c++, поиск-библиотек

Необходима библиотека\идея\алгоритм для проверки открыты ли глаза, т.е. частично нужны функции распознавания лица. 
Посоветуйте что-нибудь, что поможет в этом

Comment: [DLIB](http://dlib.net/) , [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) как пример

Comment: tensorflow, алгоритмы facenet, alignment

Comment: по моему есть еще встроенная библиотека Android SDK

Comment: Подобный вопрос на английском `SO` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311819/closed-eye-detection-opencv-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV, там даже есть стандартный пример, по поиску лиц и глаз. Ну а если найдены глаза то, определить открыты они или закрыты можно по цвету. Либо, найти расстояние между веками(при помощи детектора границ), что должно быть точнее.